# Having list of generics using the same interface

Tags: c#, generics

I'm currently trying to build a modulable system to handle the visualization of items and I'm using generic items :

```cs
interface KitchenItem
{
    public string Type { get; }
}

class Pan : KitchenItem
{
    public string Type => "Pan";

    public string GetPanBrand()
    {
        return "PanWorld";
    }
}

class Fork : KitchenItem
{
    public string Type => "Fork";

    public int GetForkSpikes()
    {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

Then I implement some visualizer with generics so I can have the good method type :

```cs
interface KitchenItemVisualizer<T> where T : KitchenItem
{
    public void DisplayVisual(T item);
}

class PanItemVisualizer : KitchenItemVisualizer<Pan>
{
    public void DisplayVisual(Pan item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"I'm built by {item.GetPanBrand()}");
    }
}

class ForkItemVisualizer : KitchenItemVisualizer<Fork>
{
    public void DisplayVisual(Fork item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"I have {item.GetForkSpikes()} spikes!");
    }
}
```

And a class to glue them all :

```cs
class KitchenController
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, KitchenItemVisualizer<KitchenItem>> _kitchenItems =
        new Dictionary<string, KitchenItemVisualizer<KitchenItem>>()
        {
            { "Pan", new PanItemVisualizer() },
            { "Fork", new ForkItemVisualizer() }
        };

    public void Display(KitchenItem item)
    {
        _kitchenItems[item.Type].DisplayVisual(item);
    }
}
```

As you can see, this won't work since my `KitchenItemVisualizer` interface generic is not covariant.

Is there a way to properly handle that? In my case, I cannot do this in the main classes `Pan` and `Fork` since its an external lib, but I still'd like to use some kind of generics or at least a modular system.

Maybe I'm doing it wrong, and I can do better in another way.

I also tried to defined a more specific interface but I end up with 2 methods then

Thanks you

Comment: There is no type safe way to do this, exactly because `KitchenItemVisualizer` is not,  and cannot safely be covariant. You will need to check the types at runtime to enforce safety.